# XSLT to PDF Preview

Tags: xslt, ide

i would like to transform a XML into PDF using a XSLT. A killer feature would be a live preview of the result - so when i edit the XSLT, some seconds later (after transforming) the resulting PDF will display in a parallel pane.

Does someone know an IDE fullfilling this requirement?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Fop looks like it does that. You could use Stylus Studio to do this for you, or Fop also has Java examples.

Comment: Is there a free alternative to Stylus Studio? Our company still purchased XMLSpy, so there's less flexibility for another commercial tool i think. Developing XSL:FO > PDF is so uncomfortable with XMLSpy...